# Python - write x rows of csv file to json file

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a csv file, which I need to write to json files in rows of 1000. The csv file has around 9,000 rows, so ideally I'd like to end up with 9 separate json files of consecutive data.

I know how to write a csv file to json - what I've been doing:

```
csvfile = open("C:\\Users\Me\Desktop\data\data.csv", 'r', encoding="utf8")

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")
out = json.dumps( [ row for row in reader ] )

with open("C:\\Users\Me\Desktop\data\data.json", 'w') as f:
f.write(out)
```

which works great. But I need the json file to be 9 split files. Now, I'm assuming that I would either:

1) attempt to count *row* and stop when it reaches 1,000

2) write the csv file to a single json file, then open the json and attempt to split it somehow.

I'm pretty lost on how to accomplish this - any help appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will read the file `data.csv` once and will create separate json files with id `data_1.json` through `data_9.json` since there are 9000 rows.

Also as long as the number of rows in `data.csv` is multiple of 1000, it will create `number_of_rows/1000` files without having to change the code.

```
csvfile = open("C:\\Users\Me\Desktop\data\data.csv", 'rb', encoding="utf8")

reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")

r = []
counter = 0
fileid = 1

for row in reader:
    r.append( row )
    counter += 1
    if counter == 999:
        out = json.dumps( r )
        fname = "C:\\Users\Me\Desktop\data\data_"+ str(fileid) + ".json"
        with open( fname, 'wb' ) as f:
            f.write( out )

        # resetting & updating variables
        fileid += 1
        counter = 0
        r = []
        out = None
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the whole CSV file into a list or rows, then write slices of length 1000 to JSON files.

```
import csv
import json

input_file = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\data\\data.csv'
output_file_template = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\data\\data_{}.json'

with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    rows = list(reader)

for i in range(len(rows) // 1000):
    out = json.dumps(rows[1000*i:1000*(i+1)])
    with open(output_file_template.format(i), 'w') as f:
        f.write(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reading the whole CSV file, you can iterate (less memory usage).

For instance, here is a simple iteration of the rows:

```
with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

During iteration, you can enumerate the rows and use this value to count the groups of 1000 rows:

```
group_size = 1000

with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for index, row in enumerate(reader):
        group_idx = index // group_size
        print(group_idx, row)
```

You should have something like this:

```
0 [row 0...]
0 [row 1...]
0 [row 2...]
...
0 [row 999...]
1 [row 1000...]
1 [row 1001...]
etc.
```

You can use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group yours rows by 1000.

Using Alberto Garcia-Raboso's solution, you can use:

```
from __future__ import division

import csv
import json
import itertools

input_file = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\data\\data.csv'
output_file_template = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\data\\data_{}.json'

group_size = 1000

with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(enumerate(rows),
                                        key=lambda item: item[0] // group_size):
       grp_rows = [item[1] for item in group]
       content = json.dumps(grp_rows)
       with open(output_file_template.format(key), 'w') as jsonfile:
           jsonfile.write(content)
```

Exemple with some fake data:

```
from __future__ import division
import itertools

rows = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8],
        [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8],
        [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8],
        [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8],
        [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]

group_size = 4
for key, group in itertools.groupby(enumerate(rows),
                                    key=lambda item: item[0] // group_size):
    g_rows = [item[1] for item in group]
    print(key, g_rows)
```

You'll get:

```
0 [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
1 [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
2 [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
3 [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
4 [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: Fantastic use of the fact that `groupby` is lazy!

Comment: `groupby` is make an iterator, and each group is also an iterator (this is why I use a comprehension list to turn the `grp_rows` into a list).

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use  a Dictreader, the regular *csv.reader* will do fine. You can also just use *itertool.islice* on the reader object to slice the data into `n` rows and dump each collection to a new file:

```
from itertools import islice, count
import csv
import json    

with open("C:\\Users\Me\Desktop\data\data.csv") as f:
    reader, cnt = csv.reader(f), count(1)
    for  rows in iter(lambda: list(islice(reader, 1000)), []):
        with open("C:\\Users\Me\Desktop\data\data{}.json".format(next(cnt))) as out:
        json.dump(rows, out)
```